# turning off sleep mode on kindle?

Tags: kindle

I'm just getting into kindle development, and I want to know if it is possible to turn off kindle's sleep mode? Or is there a way to wake it up (or a way to program it to wake up) by pushing the buttons on the front, rather than using the power button?

Not looking for anything to in-depth here, just point me in the right direction or let me know if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=127842) it is stated how to change the sleep timeout. This needs usbNetworking, which requires "jailbreak" and the usbnetworking hack: both can be downloaded from [this thread](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=88004). With usbNetworking you can telnet or ssh on your Kindle, which offers a full fledged shell with vi.

The thread about timeout change does not say that the kindle file system is read only: to edit t1_timeout you must first enter `mntroot rw`.

The usbNetworking hack requires a bit of research; read through the README_FIRST.txt included in the .zip.

And always remember that the Kindle is yet another Unix, so check also [this wonderful handbook](http://simson.net/ref/ugh.pdf) :D.